# Adding jquery using php function

Tags: php, jquery, wp-admin, javascript

I was turned down with [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75401/simple-jquery-script-not-working-in-wordpress) because I get a php error and my question revolves around jquery, but when I take out the JQUERY everything works fine. *** Again I'm creating a wordpress plugin. I am trying show and hide options. ***

Please any wordpress plugin creator with knowledge on how to implement jquery as a function please help. Please look at the question that was closed to see the script.

Very similar question: 
[Add a jQuery function to admin pages](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24237/add-a-jquery-function-to-admin-pages)

```
function accordion() {
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
var $ = jQuery;
jQuery(function ($) {
    $.fn.showHide = function (options) {

//default vars for the plugin
         var defaults = {
            speed: 1000,
            easing: '',
            changeText: 0,
            showText: 'Show',
            hideText: 'Hide'

        };
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        $(this).click(function () {
                      $('.toggleDiv').slideUp(options.speed, options.easing);

             var toggleClick = $(this);

             var toggleDiv = $(this).attr('rel');

             $(toggleDiv).slideToggle(options.speed, options.easing, function() {
             // this only fires once the animation is completed
             if(options.changeText==1){
             $(toggleDiv).is(":visible") ? toggleClick.text(options.hideText) :   toggleClick.text(options.showText);
             }
              });

          return false;

         });

    };
 })(jQuery);
</script>';
}             
 add_action( "admin_footer", "accordion" );
```

Comment: In the future, please don't open *other* questions about the same issue, when your *first* question gets closed. You should **edit the original question** to improve it, so that it can be reopened.

Comment: Sorry they unfairly closed my question and it made perfect sense.

Comment: "*Sorry they unfairly closed my question and it made perfect sense*" - No, as-written, the question should have been closed. If you have questions about why, I would recommend asking a question in meta, or popping into chat to discuss it.

Comment: Like I said it was closed unfairly and I hope stackexchange leaves it up as proof. I have no energy for people approving nonsense.

Comment: Please, 1757516, this is a network of sites maintained by volunteers taking their free time to answer all kind of questions. Cooperation is always welcomed and appreciated. If you have questions regarding how the Stack operates, check the [Meta](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/). You weren't providing enough information the previous Question nor in this one. You are lucky for having Chip's great knowledge taking a look at your problem.

Comment: I am greatful but more then once you allow them to "answer" questions in ways that are not professional and it's not fair to the user to have to take it. If they can't figure it out then they can offer suggests without boasting as if they found the resolution. The question prior said it was in a function for a plugin so it's in php tags so a php error can be present BUT it only happens when I take out the jquery code. Is that so hard to understand?

Comment: And for further proof Dan Gyale just answered my question no sarcasm or rudeness. Also if a question might be misunderstood. The comments are to further more be elaborate or they wouldn't be here, thank you.

Comment: Your previous question was closed because it _is unlikely to help any future visitors_. You have some PHP error and insisted it has to be from JavaScript. No explanation why, zero research efforts, not even basic debug data. This is not welcome here. We really want to help you but you _have_ take the first steps. I will leave this open for now, may the community decide.

Comment: Then how was Dan Gayle able to figure it out hmmm? And didn't I just post also someone with almost the identical question hmm? Seriously I know I'm getting voted down from moderators not mostly users so that explains it. Over all I got what needed, thanks!

Comment: [Should questions where a problem arose from a typo be closed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123741/should-questions-where-a-problem-arose-from-a-typo-be-closed)

Comment: I can pull ten billion questions on here that weren't debug and some nice enough helped them. Even I answered questions like that without being rude. I'm going to let people know about this.

Comment: @user1757516 said: "I'm going to let people know about this." Exactly who?

Comment: Just because it was obvious what was wrong with the code doesn't make it a good question, or useful to other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you not using the built-in `enqueue_script` function? Simply put your custom jQuery code into a file called custom.js, save it into your plugin or theme folder, then enqueue it with jQuery as a dependency:

```
<?php
function custom_scripts() {
    if (is_admin()){
        wp_enqueue_script(
            'customjs',
            get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js',
            array('jquery')
        );
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_scripts');
```

You'll need to change the `get_template_directory_uri()` function to get the proper path of your plugin, but that's basically it.

EDIT: You WANTED it in the admin. Missed that.

Comment: I will try that before and the error still persist the line that is causing the error is this:             showText: 'Show',

Comment: Can you post the exact error? Seems like you're running into the jQuery noConflict mode. Change `$('.toggleDiv').slideUp(options.speed, options.easing);` into `jQuery('.toggleDiv').slideUp(options.speed, options.easing);` and see if that makes any difference

Comment: sorry I posted the whole thing above now

Comment: You're simply mixing javascript and PHP without escaping the javascript. Either use a [PHP HEREDOC](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) or escape all of your apostrophes/quotes

Comment: You should hook this into the Plugin settings page-specific hook for `admin_enqueue_scripts`, rather than the global `wp_enqueue_scripts` - which is why I asked the OP to provide the `add_options_page()` call to the question.

Comment: You're right. In either case, the problem isn't where he's enqueuing it.

Answer (score 1):

First, write your function:

```
function wpse75424_enqueue_custom_script() {
    // Just in case, make sure script only
    // executes on the front end
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        ?>
        <script>
        // script goes here
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Next, hook your script into an appropriate hook, such as `wp_head`:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpse75424_enqueue_custom_script' );
```

Comment: the jquery is for a wordpress plugin for the admin are so wouldn't it be admin_head?

Comment: It depends. What *exact context* do you need this jQuery? e.g. do you need it specifically on a Theme or Plugin settings page?

Comment: plugin settings page

Comment: Can you add to your question the function call you use to add your Plugin settings page?